# Python: add counter on a game

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, counter

I'm new to python and to programming in general, and I find loops to be very confusing. I don't often need to use loops, but I'm currently working on a simple game (Foot, Nuke, Cockroach, similar to Rock, Paper, Scissors) and I'm pretty sure I succeeded in the basic logic, however I can't get the logic of how to make a counter for the rounds, since I have to tie it to the if statement (I guess), or something like that. I also want to make it possible to count in how many rounds the player won, and how many times it was a tie. The player is playing against a computer which generates its reply based on randoms.

```
import random

number = random.randint(1,3)

if number == 1:
    chosen1 = "Foot"
elif number == 2:
    chosen1 = "Nuke"
else:
    chosen1 = "Cockroach"

chosen2 = input("Foot, Nuke or Cockroach? (Quit ends):")

def choice(chosen1, chosen2):
    if (chosen1 == "Nuke" and chosen2=="Nuke"):
        print("You chose: ", chosen2)
        print("Computer chose: ", chosen1)
        print("You LOSE!")
    elif chosen1 == chosen2:
        print("You chose: ", chosen2)
        print("Computer chose: ", chosen1)
        print("It is a tie!")
    elif (chosen1 == "Foot" and chosen2=="Cockroach"):
        print("You chose: ", chosen2)
        print("Computer chose: ", chosen1)
        print("You LOSE!")
    elif (chosen2 == "Foot" and chosen1=="Cockroach"):
        print("You chose: ", chosen2)
        print("Computer chose: ", chosen1)
        print("You WIN!")
    elif (chosen1 == "Nuke" and chosen2=="Foot"):
        print("You chose: ", chosen2)
        print("Computer chose: ", chosen1)
        print("You LOSE!")
    elif (chosen2 == "Nuke" and chosen1=="Foot"):
        print("You chose: ", chosen2)
        print("Computer chose: ", chosen1)
        print("You WIN!")
    elif (chosen1 == "Cockroach" and chosen2=="Nuke"):
        print("You chose: ", chosen2)
        print("Computer chose: ", chosen1)
        print("You LOSE!")
    elif (chosen2 == "Cockroach" and chosen1=="Nuke"):
        print("You chose: ", chosen2)
        print("Computer chose: ", chosen1)
        print("You WIN!")
    elif chosen2 =="Quit":
        quit()

while chosen2 != "Quit":
    choice(chosen1, chosen2)
    chosen2 = input("Foot, Nuke or Cockroach? (Quit ends):")
```

Can someone please advice me how to handle this loop?
EDIT: I want the number of wins, ties and rounds to be printed AFTER the user quits.

Comment: You can add some `return True` or `return False` command in each elif and then in the while loop use a win counter to which you add 1 if return is True and use a lose counter to which you add 1 is return is False.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could add a return statement in each of the if's. Return 0 if it is a tie, 1 if the player has won and 2 otherwise.

Then simply add

> ```
> result = choice(chosen1, chosen2)
> ```

And here you have the result. Then compare it with more if's and add a tie and win variables.
It's ugly, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop seems ok. You only need to save the results in a variable which you can update. You can use a return statement for each outcome in the function called `choice` or only with a little bit effort define

```
wins = 0
ties = 0
```

at the beginning of your program and then add a

```
wins += 1
# or ties += 1
```

at each possible outcome of your program

Answer (score 0):

You could make a lookup table against wins and losses like so:

```
who_wins = {('Cockroach','Nuke'): True,
            ('Foot', 'Cockroach'): True,
            ('Nuke', 'Foot'): True}
```

That way you can run a function like so

```
def check_winner(player, cpu):
    result = who_wins.get((player,cpu), False)
    return result
```

Then check the status

```
result = check_winner(chosen2, chosen1)
if result:
   print("You won!")
   your_wins+=1
else:
   print("You lost!")
   computer_wins+=1
```

Altogether, that would look like

```
import random

your_wins, cpu_wins = 0,0

who_wins = {('Cockroach','Nuke'): True,
            ('Foot', 'Cockroach'): True,
            ('Nuke', 'Foot'): True}

def check_winner(player, cpu):
    result = who_wins.get((player,cpu), False)
    return result

while True:
    number = random.randint(1,3)

    if number == 1:
        chosen1 = "Foot"
    elif number == 2:
        chosen1 = "Nuke"
    else:
        chosen1 = "Cockroach"

    chosen2 = input("Foot, Nuke or Cockroach? (Quit ends):")

    if chosen2.lower() != "quit":
        result = check_winner(chosen2, chosen1)
        if result:
           print("You won!")
           your_wins += 1
        else:
           print("You lost!")
           cpu_wins +=1
    else:
        quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically: You need to declare a count variable, and add 1 to the variable each time a new round starts, then, you can print the round number. If you used a number(like you should) you will get an error, to fix this, use the str() method.

I have implemented this on a repl.it
https://repl.it/@conradkay/WarpedPrevailingQuerylanguage

Comment: OP don't want to count rounds, instead of this OP wants to count wins and ties.

Comment: I want to count rounds, wins and ties so this answer really helped me, however I wanna print the amount of rounds, wins and ties after the quit (I guess I worded it badly in my question), so your method of counting really helps me but whenever I try to print the number of rounds before the quit() function, it doesnt print anything

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

options = ['Foot','Nuke','Cockroach']
computer_number = random.randint(0,2)
computer_choice = options[computer_number]
def choice(chosen1, chosen2):
    print("You chose: ", chosen2)
    print("Computer chose: ", chosen1)
    if (computer_choice,player_choice) == ('Nuke','Nuke'):
        print("You LOSE!")
        return 'Loss'
    if (computer_choice==player_choice):
        print("It is a tie!")
        return 'Tie'    
    player_number = options.index(player_choice)
    result = (player_number-computer_number)%3
    if result == 2:        
        print(['You LOSE'])
        return 'Loss'
    if result == 1:
        print(['You WIN!'])
        return 'Win'

result_counts = {'Win':0,'Loss':0,'Tie':0}

while True:
    player_choice = input("Foot, Nuke or Cockroach? (Quit ends):")
    if player_choice == 'Quit':
        break
    result = choice(computer_choice, player_choice)
    results_counts[result] = results_counts[result]+1
```

Note that if you want the computer to make a different choice each time, you should put the lines

```
computer_number = random.randint(0,2)
computer_choice = options[computer_number]
```

inside the `while` loop. Also note that there's a lot of validity checking that you're omitting.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

playedRound = 0
wonRound = 0
tieRound = 0

while True:
userInput = input("Foot, Nuke or Cockroach? (Quit ends): ").capitalize()
number = random.randint(1, 3)
computerChoice = ""

if number == 1:
    computerChoice = "Foot"
elif number == 2:
    computerChoice = "Nuke"
elif number == 3:
    computerChoice = "Cockroach"



if userInput not in ["Foot", "Nuke", "Cockroach", "Quit"]:
    print("Incorrect selection.")
else:
    if userInput == "Quit":
        print("You played", playedRound, "rounds,and won", wonRound, "rounds, playing tie in", tieRound, "rounds.")
        break

    if userInput == computerChoice:
        print("You chose:", userInput)
        print("Computer chose:", computerChoice)
        print("It is a tie!")
        tieRound += 1
        playedRound += 1
    elif (userInput == "Foot" and computerChoice == "Cockroach") or \
         (userInput == "Nuke" and computerChoice == "Foot") or \
         (userInput == "Cockroach" and computerChoice == "Nuke"):
        print("You chose:", userInput)
        print("Computer chose:", computerChoice)
        print("You WIN!")
        wonRound += 1
        playedRound += 1
    else:
        print("You chose:", userInput)
        print("Computer chose:", computerChoice)
        print("You LOSE!")
        playedRound += 1
```